# Is it possible to set border, background, left and right paddings for the mention, if I use react-mentions library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use react-mentions library. I set some custom css styles for the mention(border, background, right and left paddings), you can see on the screenshots below(styles applied to the "#first-hashtag"). The problem appears when I try to select the text I typed. On the second image you can see it. This library allows to type text in a textarea field, but in order to make it possible to set some styles for the mention text it sets the text that is being typed in textarea into some spans and strong html elements. But when I want to select the text I typed, I see the problem. The text inside textarea, does not have any paddings or borders, it is just a text, that's why the text that was duplicated into span and strong elements take more space, than the text inside textarea. If I do not set borders and paddings for the duplicated text, it works properly, because all words in the duplicated text and in textarea are located under each other respectively. Please, help to fix this problem.
[screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hza5E.png)

I tried to set transparent color for the text in the textarea if user selects it. But in this case a user can't select any text, the duplicated text as well, because the textarea has z-index more than the element that contains the duplicated text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.